# Why does keyboard give me an error when using entry from tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, keyboard

I'm trying to create an autoclicker with Python just for fun. But I didn't come very far until I encountered this error message. What is the cause of this/what did I do wrong? And how can I make it work?

```
import tkinter as tk
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("200x250")

toggle_label = tk.Label(text="Choose toggle key:")
toggle_entry = tk.Entry()
toggle_label.pack()
toggle_entry.pack()


cps_label = tk.Label(text="CPS:")
cps_entry = tk.Entry()
cps_label.pack()
cps_entry.pack()
cps = cps_entry.get()


if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
    toggle_key = toggle_entry.get()
    if keyboard.is_pressed(toggle_key):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        pyautogui.leftClick()

window.mainloop()
```

```
C:\ac\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\ac\clicker.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ac\clicker.py", line 27, in <module>
    if keyboard.is_pressed(toggle_key):
  File "C:\ac\venv\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 417, in is_pressed
    steps = parse_hotkey(hotkey)
  File "C:\ac\venv\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 358, in parse_hotkey
    steps.append(tuple(key_to_scan_codes(key) for key in keys))
  File "C:\ac\venv\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 358, in <genexpr>
    steps.append(tuple(key_to_scan_codes(key) for key in keys))
  File "C:\ac\venv\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 309, in key_to_scan_codes
    normalized = normalize_name(key)
  File "C:\ac\venv\lib\site-packages\keyboard\_canonical_names.py", line 1239, in normalize_name
    raise ValueError('Can only normalize non-empty string names. Unexpected '+ repr(name))
ValueError: Can only normalize non-empty string names. Unexpected ''

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You call `toggle_entry.get()` just after `toggle_entry` is created, so what you get will be empty string.

Comment: I edited it to what you now can see in the original question. However when I press the key I have entered in the entry after pressing "q", nothing happens. Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggest you to search some tutorials on event-driven programming which tkinter GUI is based on.